# Creating an array inside of an array for json using PHP

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to replicate this json file using PHP but I cannot seem to get the array for object "location" within another array called "levels"

```
"levels": [
    {
        "id": "lower",
        "title": "Floor 26",
        "map": "images/apartment/upper.jpg",
        "minimap": "images/apartment/upper-small.png",
        "locations": [

            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "Kitchen",
                "about": "",
                "description": "<img src=\"images/logo.png\" 
                 alt=\"sdfsfs\"><p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaa<p>",
                "category": "furniture",
                "x": "0.4746",
                "y": "0.2883",
                "zoom": "1"
            },
```

This is what I have so far.

```
$connect1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "location");
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect1, "SELECT * FROM locations");

$connect2 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Floors");
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect2, "SELECT * FROM levels");


$data = array(); 
$levels = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $levels[] = $row;
}

  $data["levels"] = $levels;   

  $locations = array();


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $locations[] = $row;
    }

    $data["locations"] = $locations;
```

This is the output

```
"levels": [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "title":"Floor26",
        "map":"images\/apartment\/upper.jpg",
        "minimap":"images\/apartment\/upper-small.png"
    }
],
"locations": [
    {
```

The problem is I want `locations` to be an array within the category of levels as shown in the json file rather than `levels` array being closed after the data has been inserted. Please help. I am a complete beginner, so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you display `result2`??

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($levels);`?

Comment: Judging from what you are showing, you probably need to `array_merge()` your location array(s) and `$row` value(s), but I don't see where you get your location array(s) from.

Comment: I edited it the code. @Rasclatt how would I use array_merge for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use more descriptive variable names. They're easier to read and understand.

Second, add the locations to the levels array in a nested loop:

---

Edit: Actually, you don't need to nest the loops, since the locations are the same for every level.  If you were querying for different locations each time, or changing which locations you imported based on level, nesting would make sense.

```
$locationConnect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "location");
$locationsResult = mysqli_query($locationConnect, "SELECT * FROM locations");

$levelsConnect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Floors");
$levelsResult = mysqli_query($levelsConnect, "SELECT * FROM levels");

$data = array(); 
$levels = array(); 
$locationsArray = array();

//actually since locations appear to be the same for all results, you don't need to nest the loops, this is more efficient:
//loop location results and build locations array:
while($locationRow = mysqli_fetch_array($locationResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $locationsArray[] = $locationRow;
}

while($levelRow = mysqli_fetch_array($levelsResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){        
    //add locations array to your level row:
    $levelRow["locations"] = $locationsArray;
    //add level row to your levels array
    $levels[] = $levelRow;
}

$data["levels"] = $levels;  

//are you using this for something else? $employee_data seems to be a new array
$employee_data["locations"] = $locationsArray;
```

Comment: Made some changes, it's early here and I didn't get a lot of sleep. Ha! Give this latest version a try.

Comment: how would I loop through the data in locations? it only returns the first row.

Comment: Ok, I just updated it again, no need to nest the loops unless you're using some kind of condition per-level on which locations get included. Seems like you're including the same locations for all levels, correct?

Comment: yeah it will be the same locations for all levels

Comment: Ok, please use the latest version, it is a bit more efficient.

Comment: What if I wanted to add on to the json? add more data from another database.

Comment: Adding single key/value pairs to an array is done like this:
`$levelRow["newKey"] = newValue;`.  Just repeat what we've done here with another SQL query.